# Javascript unexpected token dot when pushing object to the array

Tags: javascript

I have below code where I am creating array of objects and when I am pushing object to the array it says that unexpected token .

```
var rulesArray = [];
var messagesArray = [];

var selectedRows = j$('table[id$="selectedProductsDiv"] tr').has('[id$="checkBoxColumn"] :checkbox:checked');

for(i = 0; i<selectedRows.length; i++){
    var element = j$(selectedRows[i]).find('input[id$="quantityId"]');

    rulesArray.push({
        j$(element).attr("name") : "required" //It shows error on this line.
    });

    messagesArray.push({
        j$(element).attr("name") : "Field cannot be blank"
    });
}
```

Can you folks please help me on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to have dynamic keys you need to construct object first with bracket notation and then push it to array:

```
var rules = {};
rules[j$(element).attr("name")] = "required";
rulesArray.push(rules);
```

In ES2015 (ES6) bracket syntax is supported during object initialization too:

```
rulesArray.push({
    [j$(element).attr("name")] : "required"
});
```